# Android google maps not responding properly after returning from Wireless and Settings started from Intent

Tags: android, google-maps

So i get a problem when i execute the following code.

```
private void checkInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
    getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
        else{
        boolean isConnected = ni.isConnected();
        if (!isConnected) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
                while(ni == null){
                    ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I start this code from the OnCreate() procedure in MapsActivity. Problem is that I get a screen which is for a moment ok but then changes color to Lightblue. I have a feeling that this is connected to the fact that I exit the wireless settings screen too fast and Mobile Internet doesn't have time to fully turn on. If I go out and came back to the activity when Internet is on everything seems to work normally.

Also i found out that putting a thread with sleep after running the code makes it work normally.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.location_activity_layout);

        //checkGPS();
        checkInternet();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        map.setSatellite(false);
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

The question is if there is a better way to resolve this than using a thread and waiting some time for internet to turn on.

Comment: Never sleep in the main application thread. You will get Application Not Responding errors.

Comment: I guess I could use AsyncTask then? but the main point I'm raising is how besides putting the thread to sleep can I loop and lose some time till Internet gets turned on

Answer (score 0):

Ok found out what was wrong i was looping the connection check in the wrong part of the code the correct code for checkInternet() is

```
private void checkInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
        else{
        boolean isConnected = ni.isConnected();
        if (!isConnected) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);  
            }
        }
        while(ni == null){
            ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo(); 
        }
    }
```